# прописать цель метрики яндекс без возможности добавления кода в форму

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

форма

```html
<form action="https://sale.1markiza.ru/index.php/zakazat-zvonok?view=form&amp;tmpl=component&amp;chronoform=zvonok&amp;event=submit&amp;tvout=view" method="post" name="display-section1" id="display-section1" data-id="display-section1" class="ui form G2-form G2-dynamic" data-valloc="inlinetext" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-dtask="send/self" data-result="replace/self" data-subanimation="1">
 <h2 class="ui header dividing">Заказать расчет<div class="sub header">Мы перезвоним Вам в ближайшее время и поможем с выбором</div></h2><div class="equal width fields" id="area_fields_11"><div class="field six wide  required"><input data-validationrules="{&quot;identifier&quot;:&quot;name_04-main&quot;,&quot;rules&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;required&quot;,&quot;prompt&quot;:&quot;\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u0437\u0430\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0435 \&quot;\u0418\u043c\u044f\&quot;&quot;}]}" data-validate="name_04-main" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name04" id="name_04" value="" type="text"></div></div><div class="field  required"><input data-validationrules="{&quot;identifier&quot;:&quot;phone04-main&quot;,&quot;rules&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;required&quot;,&quot;prompt&quot;:&quot;\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430, \u0432\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d&quot;}]}" data-validate="phone04-main" placeholder="Телефон" name="phone04" id="phone04" value="" type="text"></div><div class="field "><textarea rows="5" name="mess04" id="mess04" placeholder="Сообщение" type="textarea" data-rows="5"></textarea></div><button class="ui button red" type="submit" name="button10" id="button10" value="" data-selections="0" data-message="Please make a selection from the list">Отправить заявку</button> </form>
```

мне нужно к button добавить `onclick="ym(XXXXXX, 'reachGoal', 'TARGET_NAME'); return true;"` но форма генерируется через компонент и нет возможности вставить напрямую , есть какие то обходные пути?

Comment: Через `javascript` по `name`, не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В форме у кнопки есть `ID`, слушаем событие клика и отправляем цель метрики

```
    var button = document.getElementById("button10");
    button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        ym(XXXXXX, 'reachGoal', 'TARGET_NAME');
    },false);
```